# QuickInfo in VS 08 for custom methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, quickinfo

Is it possible (and if yes, how?) to provide custom classes, types, whatsoever with the QuickInfo-Hovers provided by the .NET-Base-classes that explain e.g. a summary or definitions of the parameters and exceptions?

(Example for clarification)

[QuickInfo http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/9720/quickinfo.jpg](http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/9720/quickinfo.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [XML Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) to your method.

[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) is a free tool that will give you a context menu option that has a stab at it for you ;)

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XML comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) in your code. Decorate your custom method with comments:

```
/// <summary>
/// Some description
/// </summary>
/// <param name="arg">Some argument</param>
static void SomeCustomMethod(int arg)
{

}
```

[Enable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3260k4x7.aspx) XML comments when compiling the assembly. Add the MyAssembly.XML to the references and your custom method description will be shown.